# Remove duplicates from const array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I have to implement a function in `C` with the following signature: `int *unici(const int *vec, size_t size, size_t *newsize)`, where `vec` is a `const` array of `int`s, `size` is the size of the array, and `*newsize` is the size of the new array without duplicates.

This function has to create a new array on the heap and put the values from `vec` into the array without duplicates.

Example: If `vec` is `[2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 9]`, `size` is `8`, then the new array should be `[2, 4, 5, 7, 9]` with `*newsize` equal to `5`.

I tried to implement it, but I don't know how to remove duplicates and put into new array.

```
int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b) 
{
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

int *unici(const int *vec, size_t size, size_t *newsize)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;

    qsort(vec, size, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

    size_t count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //finding for duplicates 
        if (vec[i] == vec[i + 1])
            count++;
    }

    *newsize = size - count;
    int *tmp = malloc(*newsize * sizeof(int));

    //now I've to put in tmp values from vec without duplicates
}
```

EDIT: that's my solution, I figured out, by the way, thank you all!

```
int *unici(const int *vec, size_t size, size_t *newsize)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;

    int *tmp = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        tmp[i] = vec[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (tmp[i] == tmp[j])
            {
                for (size_t k = j; k<size; k++)
                {
                    tmp[k] = tmp[k + 1];
                }
                size--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    *newsize = size;
    return tmp;

}
```

Comment: What is the problem?  malloc the new array to the size of the old one, copy in the values except for dupes.  Keep count of the new size as you are doing above, so that the caller knows the last valid entry.  Should be good, no?

Comment: I mean, if you're that bothered about the over-malloc 'cos of a lot of dupes, you can realloc it before the return, if you think it's worth it, else just leave the possibly-overisze malloc as it is.

Comment: Note that your comparison function will fail if the numbers in the array are big enough and of opposite signs such that the subtraction overflows.  That's undefined behaviour.  It may be good enough for the test cases, but be wary in general.  Using `return (x > y) - (x < y);` for two values `x` and `y` works (but you'd probably not want to write `*(int *)a` etc out 4 times).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't want `const int*` in `unici` it throws the warning

```
passing argument 1 of ‘qsort’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
```

And then we go on, to allocating memory for each of the integers that are non-duplicate.

```
int *unici(int *v, size_t size, size_t *newsize)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;

    qsort(v, size, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

    int *temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
    if (temp == NULL){
        perror("Error ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    (*newsize)= 0;
    temp[(*newsize)++] = v[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] != v[i-1]){
            int *tt = realloc(temp,(*newsize+1)*sizeof *tt);
            if (tt == NULL){
                perror("Error ");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            temp = tt;
            temp[(*newsize)++] = v[i];
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

There are two points with this code

- Here the array is supposed to be constant. So it must do duplicate of the array and then do the sorting and then eliminate duplicates and resize again as per the unique elements present. This is having the benefit that the `const` removal as mentioned - you don't have to do that.
- In my code I have used reallocate for each of the elements - which is an overkill. So what to do then? Well as said earlier we will allocate it to maximum size and then reduce the size to the unique list. That again leaves us to debate should we reduce it every time? (Suppose 1-2 positions left out.) Well then it is not so much needed to resize but well one can do that. It's implementor's choice to some extent.

The idea of this simple shrinking is being implemented here:-

```
int *unici(const int *vv, size_t size, size_t *newsize)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;

    int *v = malloc(sizeof *v * size);
    if (v == NULL){
        perror("Error in malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memcpy(v, vv, size*sizeof*v);
    qsort(v, size, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

    (*newsize)= 0;
    int last = v[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] != last){
            v[(*newsize)++] = last;
            last = v[i];
        }
    }
    v[(*newsize)++] = v[size-1];

    int *temp = realloc(v, (*newsize)*sizeof *v);
    if (temp == NULL){
        perror("Error in realloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    v = temp;
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic approaches.

---

Duplicate the original array. Sort the elements in the new array, and use a loop to keep only the first one of any runs (more than one same value):

```
int   *result; /* This is the duplicate array; sorted */
size_t i = 0;  /* Loop index */
size_t n = 0;  /* Unique elements in the duplicate array */

while (i < size) {
    const int  c = result[i++];

    /* Skip if there are more than one consecutive c */
    while (i < size && c == result[i])
        i++;

    /* Copy the unique elements back to the beginning
       of the array. */
    result[n++] = c;
}
```

You can, if you want, reallocate `result` to `n * sizeof result[0]` bytes.

Store the number of unique elements `n` to `*newsize`, and return `result`.

---

Allocate the result array, but don't bother copying the values yet. Instead of sorting (to make duplicate values consecutive), use a double loop to check whether each value is unique (already in the result array) or not, and only copy the unique ones to the result array:

```
int   *result; /* Allocated for 'size' elements */
size_t i, j;   /* Loop indexes */
size_t n = 0;  /* Unique elements in the duplicate array */

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    /* Find first duplicate in result. */
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if (result[j] == vec[i])
            break;

    /* If no duplicates found, add to result. */
    if (j >= n)
        result[n++] = vec[i];
}
```

You can, if you want, reallocate `result` to `n * sizeof result[0]` bytes.

Store the number of unique elements `n` to `*newsize`, and return `result`.

---

Which one is the better approach, depends on how the `result` set is used, and whether it is useful for it to be in sorted order. If sorted order is useful, or if speed is important and the order does not matter, the sort approach is likely better.

(The efficiency of the sort approach depends on the efficiency of the sort function. Many sort functions are known that have *O(size × log size)* time complexity; for a truly huge amount of data, an *O(size)* radix sort can be used (because the number of values is known beforehand). Note that a radix sort will only beat other sorts for very large `size`s, typically in the millions.)

In some cases, it might be important that the `result` set is in the same order as the `vec` was, but with the duplicates removed. Then, the second approach is the obvious choice. Its time complexity is *O(size × n)*, which means that it slows down the larger the array and the set of unique elements are.

Answer (score 1):

Since you sorted your vector it should be easy. Iterate over the vector.. and copy values if they don't match with the previous value. Something like this (not verified compilable code):

```
size_t src;
size_t dst;

for (src = 0, dst = 0; src < size; src++)
{
    // skip check for first element; compare with previous and if they are the same just move on
    if (src > 0 && vec[src] == vec[src - 1])
        continue;

    tmp[dst] = vec[src];
    dst++;
}
```

Comment: Also note that in your original code you compare with the next value. For the last element this is undefined and may cause a crash or report in a duplicate falsely.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that.. I'm gonna improve, anyway thank you for your support!

Comment: Looks like you found your own solution with the input from others. Way to go! :)